# convert b'\x10’ to int 16 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use python 2.7.
 I want to convert `b'\x10'` to 16 in python.
 I have tried `int()` function but failed.

The final aim is: I want to do this kind of bit calculation:

```
b'\x00' << 8 | b'\x03'
```

Comment: `\x10` would be `16` (not `10`) as a base 10 integer.

Comment: that‘s right， how to convert？’

Comment: `ord(b'\x10'.decode('utf-8'))# prints 16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the code of a character, use the `ord()` function.

```
ord('\x10')
```

will return `16`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to read individual bytes of a bytestring:

```
>>> x=b'\x10'
>>> x[0]
16
```